# You have to block on webflux to operate. Is there a way to operate without blocking?

Tags: spring-webflux, webclient, blocking

work

```java
        WebClient webClient = WebClient.create("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");

        return  webClient.post()
                .uri("")
                .header("Authorization", "key=test")
                .bodyValue("")
                .retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class).block();
```

not work

```java
        WebClient webClient = WebClient.create("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");

        return  webClient.post()
                .uri("")
                .header("Authorization", "key=test")
                .bodyValue("")
                .retrieve();
```

how to change my code??
I don't want to use the block.

Comment: We need more context, what application is it a pure webflux application or is it a web application. What does the code that call this look like? Have you read the reactor getting started documentation?

Comment: This is a scheduler.

Comment: Please read my comment again, i asked several questions `this is a scheduler` is not an answer to any of my questions.

Comment: This is a Web server and is turning the scheduler on the server.
I didn't quite understand the meaning of whether it was a pure webflux application or a web application.
I'm using it as a server, but I don't know which area the server belongs to.
I'm not a server developer, but I'm writing the server code, so I'm not good at the basics.
I don't have a boss, so I have no one to ask.

Comment: The code you call is 
```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 60000)
public void init() throws Exception {
try {
```

Comment: Update your question with this information don write it a comment please.

Answer (score 1):

Webflux is using the reactive programming paradigm. This differs quite a lot from the traditional imperative approach.

One big difference is that **nothing happens until you subscribe**.

You should handle it in a way like this:

```java
WebClient webClient = WebClient.create("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");

        return  webClient.post()
                .uri("")
                .header("Authorization", "key=test")
                .bodyValue("")
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(YourResponseObject.class)
                .flatMap(yourResponseObject -> dataRepository.save(yourSavedResponse))
                .subscribe(yourSavedResponse -> 
                                log.info("saved {} to database", yourSavedResponse(),
                                throwable -> log.error("an error occured", throwable));
```

Your code example that uses `.block()` works because, your call to `block()` turns the whole snippet from being reactive into blocking code.